# Delete multiple folder with Powershell

Tags: powershell

i need a script that delete a multiple folder, when windows services was stopped. I writed this scrit:

```
[Array] $Services = 'LAS_LMB','LAS_LWS','LAS_CORE';

$las_path = "D:"
$tomcat_path = @('tomcat_core', 'tomcat_lmb', 'tomcat_web')
$log_folder = "$las_path\tomcat_*\logs"
$temp_folder = "$las-path\temp\*"
$localhost_folder = "$las_path$tomcat_path\work\Catalina\localhost"

# loop through each service, if its stopped, delete some folders
foreach($ServiceName in $Services)
{
    $arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName
    
    if ($arrService.Status -eq 'Stopped')
    {
        Start-Sleep -s 5
        Remove-Item $localhost_folder, $temp_folder -Force -Recurse -Verbose
        Get-ChildItem -Path  $log_folder -Recurse -include * | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)} | Remove-Item -Verbose
        if ($arrService.Status -eq 'Running')
            {
              Write-Host "To delete Logs, Temporary Datas etc. must all serveices be stopped. Please start script Stopservices.ps1 first"
            }
     }
 }
```

When i started the script, the skript check that service is stopped, but only one. I need when all of services are stoped, to delete the folders. For example 1. service -and 2.service -and 3.service.
I don't know how to use this funktion:
By start the script must to ask that write a name a service. For example:
$Dienste = Read-Host "Please enter the Services"
I write las1, las2, las3 and this values must be enter in:

```
[Array] $Services = $Dienste in this format 
[Array] $Services = 'las1','las2','las3';
```

Thx a lot.

Comment: _"By start the script must to ask that write a name a service"_ -- This should be posted as a separate question (if an existing question that answers the problem cannot be found), so are the rules on StackOverflow. See [ask]. Hint: Use the `-split` operator.

Comment: this >>> `"$las-path\temp\*"` <<< is apparently wrong. i think you need an underscore where you have a hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

> I need when all of services are stoped, to delete the folders.

`Get-Service` accepts an array of service names, so you could do the following to wait for all services to be stopped:

```
while( Get-Service $Services | Where-Object Status -ne 'Stopped' ) { Sleep 3 }

# Now delete the folders...
```

The `Get-Service` call retrieves all services that are defined in the `$Services` array. This can be [wildcard patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.1) like `Name*`.

From these services we select all services that are not stopped, using the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.1) cmdlet. The `while` loops condition will be fullfilled, as long as the pipeline returns *something*, meaning at least one service is not stopped. If all services are stopped, then `Where-Object` won't output anything and the `while` loop exits.

The `Sleep 3` (seconds) is there so we don't use more system resources than necessary. The `3` doesn't have a special significance, you could use `1` or `5`, it doesn't really matter. Just don't busy-loop, to give the system a chance to do other things while your script is waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for explanation. I wrote this. It's a syntaxis a right writed?

```
[Array] $Services = 'service1','service2','service3';

$las_path = "D:\LAS"
$tomcat_path = "$las_path\tomcat_*"
$log_folder = "$las_path\tomcat_*\logs"
$temp_folder = "$las-path\temp\*"
$localhost_folder = "$las_path\tomcat_path\work\Catalina\localhost"

# loop through each service, if its stopped, delete some folders
foreach($ServiceName in $Services)
{
    $arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName
    while( Get-Service $Services | Where-Object Status -ne 'Stopped') {Sleep 3 }
{
        Remove-Item $localhost_folder, $temp_folder -Force -Recurse -Verbose
        Get-ChildItem -Path  $log_folder -Recurse -include * | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)} | Remove-Item -Verbose
        
        if ($arrService.Status -eq 'Running')
            {
              Write-Host "To delete Logs, Temporary Datas etc. must all serveices be stopped. Please start script Stopservices.ps1 first"
            }
    
    }
}
```

Thx.